# What is the best/ quickest way to get an image using HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, asp.net-web-api

I currently have this method:

```
  public HttpResponseMessage Get(string FileId, string VersionId)
        {
            byte[] fileContents;

            var file = DataRepository.GetSingle<FileModel>(ObjectId.Parse(FileId));
            var fileDir = file.Dir + "/"+VersionId+ file.FileExtension;
            var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var image = new Bitmap(WebRequest
                    .Create(fileDir)
                    .GetResponse()
                    .GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    image.Save(memoryStream, StorageServiceHelper.GetImageFormatFromFileName(fileDir));
                    fileContents = memoryStream.ToArray();

                    var stream = new MemoryStream(fileContents);
                    result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
                    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(file.MediaType);
                }
            }

            return result;
```

So for each image request it calls this method, but it seems to be painfully slow on the first request(at least 1 second per request of a 5 kb file). Is there a quicker way to do this?
            }

Comment: The speed of light is finite. If you cannot get a connection with less latency - physically move your server closer to the server you're requesting http from.

Comment: which statement exactly is slow? Can't the `memoryStream` be put in to `new StreamContent(stream);` (first set the `memoryStream.Position = 0;`)

Comment: The whole method is. Its called 8 time per page (8 itmes per page) I've just noticed there is a db call for each image. Im going to see how it is without the database call

Comment: Slightly faster without the db call but still slow

Answer (score 0):

that looks like a pretty complicated method, but I don't know the details of why you are doing it that way.  In  any case, this is my controller that returns an image:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(HttpRequestMessage request, int id)
    {

        byte[] img = await _repo.GetImgAsync(id);//gets image from database.

        HttpResponseMessage msg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new ByteArrayContent(img)
        };
        msg.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");

        return msg;
    }
```

Also, if its only the first request that is slow, it may be Asp.Net starting the app.  You can see the same thing on a live server if you restart the app pool in IIS.